# Firefox ugly after update to 16.10

Tags: firefox, 16.10

After updating Ubuntu to 16.10 (from 16.04) my Firefox looks ugly. As you can see from the screenshot the lines around the address bar as well as some others that used to be smoother are now too thick and ugly.

[image]

Things that I have tried without success:

- Change to another GTK theme.
- Check how FireFox looks in other user accounts including Guest.
- Disable the `Use hardware acceleration when available` option.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Problem solved after upgrading to Firefox 50.

Answer (score 0):

I think mine (with default theme) looks exactly like the screenshot you've posted too. However to give your Firefox a beautiful and impressive look and feel you can try installing [complete themes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/complete-themes/).

For example, [Ark theme](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/arc-theme) looks great on Firefox.

Comment: Thank you, Ark looks great indeed, although this does not completely solve the issue as the pop-up menus still look ugly :(

Answer (score 0):

According to a moderator on the #firefox channel on irc.freenode.org this is due to 16.10 using gtk+ 3.20 (this can be checked by you with running `apt-cache policy libgtk-3-0`). 16.04, on the other hand, uses `libgtk-3.18.9-1`, which I can confirm doesn't have this problem. Apparently some gtk themes, but not many, has fixes for this problem.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that it should be gtk related. I do not plan to downgrade, but now I know what the problem is. Hopefully there will be an update of gtk, firefox or the default ubuntu gtk themes fixing this...